# access to return object from asp.net in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have jquery function:

```
function CheckStatus() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:1111/test.myControl/GetDone",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {
                console.info(data.GetStatusResult);
                if (data.IsDone) {
                    result = true;
                    CheckForFile();
                }
                else
                    result = false;      
            }
        });

    }
```

here the function that i call from asp.net mvc3:

```
public MStatus GetDone()
        {
            ......

            return new MStatus {  IsDone = IsDone, NowDateTime=DateTime.Now};
        }
```

as you see  this function returns object `MStatus` with variable `IsDone`. I tried to check the value of `IsDone`, but I couldn't.

Can someone tell me how to solve my problem?

Comment: you need to clarify your question. what you are trying to achieve? what errors/difficulties are you having? the clearer the question is the faster you will receive an answer :)

Comment: use a Firebug to see what the ajax call returns

Comment: You Right ! but my english isn't so good... ,  however i found my Mistake i have to replace the line :  data.IsDone                           with :  data.GetStatusResult.IsDone

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :-

```
if(data.d.IsDone){ }
```

Hope this helps

EDIT:-

```
function GetTrainingDetails(id) {
        $('#<%=updProgress.ClientID%>').css("display", "block");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/_layouts/TrainingSheet/TrainingSourceBrowse.aspx/GetTrainingDetail",
            data: "{'trainingId': '" + id + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                AjaxSucceeded(msg);
            },
            error: AjaxFailed
        });
    }

    function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
        var res = result.d;

        $('#<%= lblType.ClientID%>').html(res.TrainingType);
        $('#<%= lblOrganizer.ClientID %>').html(res.Organizer);
        $('#<%= lblTrainer.ClientID %>').html(res.Trainer);
        $('#<%= lblLevel.ClientID %>').html(res.Level);
        $('#<%= lblCategory.ClientID %>').html(res.Category);
        $('#pDetails').html(res.Summary);
        $('#headingTitle').html(res.Training);

        $('#<%=updProgress.ClientID %>').css("display", "none");
        $('#divDetails').slideDown("slow");
    }

    function AjaxFailed(result) {
        alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
        $('#<%=updProgress.ClientID %>').css("display", "none");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the request is a AJAX request and send a JSON package

```
var status = new MStatus {  IsDone = IsDone, NowDateTime=DateTime.Now};
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
  return Json( new { IsDone = status.IsDone, NowDateTime = status.NowDateTime }
              , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}else{
  return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method need to return an `ActionResult`

```
public ActionResult GetDone()
{
    ......

    var status = new MStatus { IsDone = IsDone, NowDateTime=DateTime.Now};
    return Json(status, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```